# Ansys SpaceClaim parameter study

Tags: ansys

i am working on my bachelor thesis and I am supposed to do a parameter study within ansys SpaceClaim. Basically I have a cross sectional geometry (on paper) and need to do the following steps:

1. Convert it to some parameterised sketch within Ansys
2. For a given set of parameters, adjust the sketch according to my parameters.
3. Generate a body from the sketch within Ansys
4. Compute thermal field
5. Repeat from step 2

Since I have never worked with Ansys, I do not know how to proceed and which tools I am supposed to use. Could someone here give me a hint which tools would work out best? Is it possible to do parameterised sketches within SpaceClaim and if so, how would I adjust these parameters?

I am very happy for any help!
Greetings Finn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to ANSYS and SpaceClaim, then the first thing you should do is just open YouTube, open ANSYS Learning Channel and watch the tutorials for SpaceClaim there. On top of that, watch videos uploaded by other channels as which explains other SpaceClaim features in detail.

I am going to assume you already know how to draw the sketch in SpaceClaim. After making that sketch, you can click the option 'Dimensions' which can be seen in toolbar under 'Sketch' ribbon on top. Then you can click on any edge, circle etc that you have sketched and change its dimension on the bottom left tree under 'General', as shown in the picture below.

[image]

The problem with SpaceClaim, as I have observed, is that you cannot parameterize these dimensions. As far as I can recall, you have to manually open the SpaceClaim everytime and then change these parameters manually. There might be an option to parameterize these dimensions but I am not aware of it; maybe you can access online website of SpaceClaim to check how that can be done if it is possible.

For DesignModuler in ANSYS, it is easy to parameterize the dimensions. Just click this option and a ***P*** will appear, meaning that this dimension has been parameterized and you can change it directly by opening the parameter table (seen directly on ANSYS Workbench window). There is no need to open the DesignModuler over and over again if the dimension(s) need to be changed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that explanation!
I found out that you can parametrize in SpaceClaim using DS in the parameter dame in case you are interested. 
DesignModuler seems to work better when changing geometry relations via workbench though, so I think that will be the better option.